# Rails 5 - how to add a prefix for a scaffold route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, routes

I have generated a scaffold model `car`.

So if I want to create a new car, the URL looks like this: `/cars/new`. I need to pass another information to the URL and the easiest way is to simply add it as a parameter in the end, so the URL would look something like `/cars/new?listing=123`.

What I am trying to do is to get something like this in the URL: `/l/123/cars/new` (l = listings). Same for the other actions as well (eg. `/l/123/cars/4/edit`.

How do I need to modify the routes for such an example? `listing` is another model, and every `listing` has a car.

Thank you

Comment: You already wrote that query parameters would have been the easiest way. Why do you try to avoid them? What are you optimizing for?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't achieve this with *resourceful* way. You have to define **non-resourceful** routes to achieve what you want. For instance, the route for `cars#new` would be defined like below

```
get /:listing_id/:extra_param/cars/new, to: "cars#new"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use nested resources:

```
resources :listings do
  resources :cars
end
```

It will generate routes like `listings/:listing_id/cars/:id`. If you do not have `listings` controller or you do not want to generate routes for it just use `resources :listings, only: [] do ...`